# How to implement onItemClick and onLongItemClick in RecycleView for Kotlin in android

Tags: android, kotlin

- I have used Kotlin for implementing click listeners
- How to properly use it, currently click is not detecting, I am not able to detect click using below code.

---

```
  class AdptEvents (val items: MutableList<TestModel>, val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>() {

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, p1: Int): ViewHolder {
            return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_event, parent, false))
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return items.size
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            holder?.tvAnimalType?.text = items.get(position).getName()

            holder?.rootView.setOnClickListener{
                clickEventRow(items,position)
                true
            }
            holder?.rootView.setOnLongClickListener {
                clickEventRow(items,position)
                true
            }
        }

        private fun clickEventRow( items: MutableList<TestModel>, position: Int ) {
            Toast.makeText(context,items[position].getName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

    }

    class ViewHolder (view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        // Holds the TextView that will add each animal to
        val tvAnimalType = view.txtTitle!!
        val rootView = view.eventListRootId!!
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need anything else

```
  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            holder?.tvAnimalType?.text = items.get(position).getName()

            holder?.rootView.setOnClickListener{
              // code here
            }
            holder?.rootView.setOnLongClickListener {
               //code here
            }
        }
```

Comment: The problem is i have added the click event to root view Id. Adding it to its child did the trick in the xml

Answer (score 0):

Change your view holder. Also, if you need to get index, use `adapterPosition` variable.

```
inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    // Holds the TextView that will add each animal to
    val tvAnimalType = itemView.txtTitle!!
    val rootView = itemView.eventListRootId!!

    init {
        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(context, "OnClick", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        // OnLongClick and etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks not triggering the click

Answer (score 0):

If you need to handle root view click events apply it dirrectly

```
class ViewHolder (view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    // Holds the TextView that will add each animal to
    val tvAnimalType = view.txtTitle!!

    view.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(view.context, "OnClick", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
    view.setOnLongClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(view.context, "OnLongClick", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        true
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks not triggering the click

Comment: @Devrath does your `RecyclerView` above other view's?

Comment: The problem is i have added the click event to root view Id. Adding it to its child did the trick in the xml